# regex how to get a non-greedy match

Tags: regex

Let's say I have a text:

```
cool randomtext1 cool randomtext2 cool randomtext3 good cool
```

How would I match the most inner

```
cool randomtext3 good
```

When I try

```
r'cool.*?good'
```

It matches

```
cool randomtext1 cool randomtext2 cool randomtext3 good
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @stribizhev 0 not a duplicate, but a spinoff question from my original

Comment: Same *tempered greedy token* solution here and there. Here, the answerer does not even name the term.

Comment: nevermind, you are right...:-), I didn't see the link before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this look-around based regex:

```
r'\bcool\b(?:(?!\b(cool|good)\b).)*\bgood\b'
```

Here `(?:(?!\b(cool|good)\b).)*` will match 0 or more of any text that is not `cool` or `good`. `\b` has been used for word boundaries.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fP8jI3/2)

This will match `cool randomtext3 good`.

**Code:**

```
p = re.compile(ur'\bcool\b(?:(?!\b(cool|good)\b).)*\bgood\b')
test_str = u"cool randomtext1 cool randomtext2 cool randomtext3 good cool"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```